$2021$th derivative of a function at $x=0$
Consider the two functions $p(x) = 1 – x + x^2 – x^3 + .... + x^{1500}$ and $q(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + .... + x^{1500}$ .
The absolute value of $h^{(2021)}(0)$, where $h(x) = p(x)\cdot q(x)$ and $h^{(k)}$ denote the $k$th order derivative of $h(x)$
with respect to $x$ is what??
My approach - I tried differentiating it $2-3$ times to observe a pattern but it did not help me. Also I tried by using first principle of differentiation which gave no clue to me.

Instead of the power 1500, try 2,4,6,8.

It is the same as finding the coefficient of $x^{2021}$.

No calculations are needed. Observe that $q(x)=p(-x).$ Thus $$f(x):=p(x)q(x)=p(x)p(-x)$$ Hence $f(x)$  is an even function. Thus all its odd derivatives are odd functions, which follows from the formula $$f^{(k)}(x)=(-1)^kf^{(k)}(-x)$$ Therefore they  vanish  at the point $0$
for $k$ odd.

Using Leibniz rule, we compute:
\begin{align*}
h^{(2021)}(x)&=\sum_{j=0}^{2021}\binom{2021}{j}p^{(j)}(x)q^{(2021-j)}(x).
\end{align*}
Notice that $p^{(j)}=0$ for all $j>1500$ and $q^{(2021-j)}=0$ for all $j<521$ (as both $p$ and $q$ have degree $1500$). So:
\begin{align*}
h^{(2021)}(x)&=\sum_{j=521}^{1500}\binom{2021}{j}p^{(j)}(x)q^{(2021-j)}(x).
\end{align*}
Evaluating at $x=0$, we obtain:
\begin{align*}
h^{(2021)}(0)&=\sum_{j=521}^{1500}\binom{2021}{j}p^{(j)}(0)q^{(2021-j)}(0).
\end{align*}
We compute:
\begin{align*}
p^{(j)}(0)&=\frac{\mathrm{d}^j}{\mathrm{d}x^j}\left(x\longmapsto\sum_{i=0}^{1500}(-1)^ix^i\right)_{\vert x=0}=\left(x\longmapsto\sum_{i=j}^{1500}(-1)^i\frac{1500!}{j!}x^{i-j}\right)_{\vert x=0}=(-1)^j\frac{1500!}{j!},\\
%
q^{(2021-j)}(0)&=\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2021-j}}{\mathrm{d}x^{2021-j}}\left(x\longmapsto\sum_{i=0}^{1500}x^i\right)_{\vert x=0}=\left(x\longmapsto\sum_{i=j}^{1500}\frac{1500!}{(2021-j)!}x^{i-(2021-j)}\right)_{\vert x=0}=\frac{1500!}{(2021-j)!}.
\end{align*}
Gathering everything together, we eventually get:
\begin{align*}
h^{(2021)}(0)&=\sum_{j=521}^{1500}\binom{2021}{j}(-1)^j\frac{1500!}{j!}\frac{1500!}{(2021-j)!}\\
%
&=(1500!)^2\sum_{j=521}^{1500}\binom{2021}{j}(-1)^j\frac{1}{j!}\frac{1}{(2021-j)!}\\
%
&=\frac{(1500!)^2}{2021!}\sum_{j=521}^{1500}\binom{2021}{j}^2(-1)^j.
\end{align*}

We can write $p(x)=\dfrac{x^{1501}+1}{x+1}$ and $q(x)=\dfrac{x^{1501}-1}{x-1}$. Hence, $h(x)=p(x)\,q(x)=\dfrac{x^{3002}-1}{x^2-1}=1+x^2+x^4+\dots+x^{3000}$.
Since the coefficient of $x^{2021}$ is $0$ here, $h^{(2021)}(0)=0$.

I ignored this answer because of votes while I was still unsatisfied by other responses. This is the most effective way to reach the exact answer. Thanks!
